# Rails：undefined method `url_for' for #<Aws::S3::Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

- ruby:2.6.3
- rails:5.2.5

I use those gems ↓

- gem 'devise'
- gem 'paperclip'
- gem 'aws-sdk'

I can't show the image because of an error.

```
  def authenticated_image_url(style)
    profile_img.s3_object(style).url_for(:read, :secure => true)
  end
```

I want to give permissions to the images to be saved to S3, so that we don't publish all the images.
However. There is an error in the method to create a URL that references an image on S3 that is protected by permissions.

```
<%= image_tag(@user.authenticated_image_url(:thumb), class: "img-fluid rounded-start img-thumbnail") %>
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  def update_without_current_password(params, *options)
     params.delete(:current_password)

     if params[:password].blank? && params[:password_confirmation].blank?
       params.delete(:password)
       params.delete(:password_confirmation)
     end

     result = update_attributes(params, *options)
     clean_up_passwords
     result
  end

  has_attached_file :profile_img,
                    :styles => {
                        :thumb  => "100x100",
                        :medium => "200x200",
                        :large => "600x400"
                    },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_permissions => :private,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension"

  validates_attachment_content_type :profile_img, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

  def authenticated_image_url(style)
    profile_img.s3_object(style).url_for(:read, :secure => true)
  end
end
```

How do I do to solution this problem? Ple tell me. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're looking for `presigned_url`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
Is it correct that the images to be stored in S3 should have permissions to prevent them from being made public? There is an error in the method to create a URL that references an image on S3 that is protected by permissions.

Comment: If a file is not public (`acl: "public-read"`), then users need to use its `presigned_url` to be able to retrieve it. I think it's your bucket settings that set the default visibility if you don't specify `acl` on upload.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your reply. I'll try it as I look into it. Maybe I will ask you again.